# SQL Server SP called from PHP returns empty result; in Studio and elsewhere, returns multiple rows

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure. When I run it in SSMS, it returns 312 rows; ditto when I run it from Visual FoxPro code. But when I use the same call in my PHP code, I get an empty result. By empty, I mean that testing it with the empty() function returns true; sqlsrv_has_rows() also returns true, but when I attempt to loop through the result, I never enter the loop.

I'm using the same calling structure to set up and execute the call with several other SPs, and they work. In fact, if I modify the page I'm working on, so that it calls a different SP, I get results.

I'm not even sure what code to show here, but here's the key code from the page containing the call:

```
<?php
$articles = getdata("GetArticles","'','',''");
while( $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $articles)) {
?>
```

That's followed by a mix of HTML and PHP to populate a table.

Here's the getdata function:

```
function getdata($spname, $params, $errorstring = 'Unable to retrieve requested data') {
$conn = connect2db();
$query = "EXECUTE ".$spname;
if (!$params == '') {
    $query .= " ".$params;
}
//echo "query = ".$query."\r\n";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
//echo "result = ".$result."\r\n";

if ($result == false) {
    $errors = sqlsrv_errors();
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error['message'];
    }
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

return $result;

}
```

connecttodb is another function that actually makes the database connection. It's definitely working.

The SP is a single query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [XXXXXX].[GetArticles] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Pubs char(400) = '', 
    @Types char(400) = '',
    @Years char(400) = ''
AS

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT Article.Title, 
       ArticleType.Name AS ArticleType,
       URL,
       Publication.Title AS Publication,
       DateName(m, DATEFROMPARTS(Article.[Year], Article.[Month], 1)) + ', ' + CONVERT(char(4), [Year])
    FROM Article
      JOIN ArticleType
        ON Article.iTypeID = ArticleType.iID
      JOIN Publication
        ON Article.iMagazineID = Publication.iID
    WHERE (@Pubs = '' 
          OR iMagazineID IN 
            (SELECT * FROM Split(@Pubs, ',')))
      AND (@Types = ''
          OR iTypeID IN
            (SELECT * FROM Split(@Types, ',')))
      AND (@Years = ''
          OR CONVERT(CHAR(4), [Year]) IN
            (SELECT * FROM Split(@Years, ',')))
    ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC            
END
```

EDIT: To simplify the situation, I create a new SP with no parameters that simply retrieves all records (which is what I need in some cases) and modified the page to call the new SP. As before, the SP works in SSMS, but retrieves no useful records.

I also need to clarify that it seems that I'm getting a record, but it's entirely empty. Specifically, for testing, I added this code after the call to the SP:

```
if (is_null($articles)) {
    echo "Null return";
}
else {
    $obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object($articles);
    if (is_null($obj)) {
        echo "First object is null";
    }
    else {
        if (empty($obj)) {
            echo "First object is empty";
        }
    }
```

What gets echoed on the page is "First object is empty".
    }

Comment: Show the exact params you are passing in and how you run it in SSMS.

Comment: Two things. 1) You should pass your params as an array not a string. 2) Because you're passing it as a string that means you need to make sure it's properly formatted when doing to the server. So if you pass 'cat, dog, monkey', you probably want it to do `EXECUTE procedure 'cat', 'dog', 'monkey'` what it's actually doing is `EXECUTE procedure cat, dog, monkey`

Comment: It looks like you are not passing any params, also make sure that your are opening the stored procedure in the correct database.

Comment: In the case that's not working, I'm not passing any params. The call is: EXECUTE GetArticles. That works perfectly in SSMS; so does EXECUTE GetArticles '','',''. When I do pass params, each is potentially a comma-separated list, so the call is something like EXECUTE GetArticles '1,3','','2,3,4'.

Comment: @Chuck, I only have the one database available in this connection, and all the other SPs are executing correctly. Is there something I should be checking?

Comment: @TamarE.Granor, The problem has to be in the PHP code, you might have to step into your getdate function, and see if you have a connection problem or just a error in the code. The SQL part looks good, and you said that it worked in SSMS, so it had to be the PHP part. Sorry, I don't do PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The last field in the field list is a complicated expression (basically building a "month, year" string). By accident, I hadn't given the field a name using AS. Once I did, it all works.

My guess as to why this fails is that the sqlsrv library is using the field name to generate the property names on the PHP side, and whatever default SQL Server offered was causing trouble.